# Getting country data from PayPal transaction export, or API

Tags: paypal

The "country" field in the PayPal transaction history CSV exports is almost always empty. However, PayPal must know the country where a transaction originates, and in fact tools such as Putler can display the country for nearly all transactions.

I wish to obtain this data myself, but since the export doesn't appear to have it, should I obtain it by using the API? And which of the APIs wold be appropriate to use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can probably do this using the API. First you'll need to [search](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) your account's transaction history. After that you'll get a list of transaction ID's, you can then [retrieve information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) about a specific ID which includes the country code of the buyer.

You can see more details here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/

Comment: This will work, but if you have many transactions will probably be VERY slow. I'm *not* an expert on PayPal's multitude of reporting solutions but I would recommend poking around (or asking them) for a solution that doesn't require an internet round trip per transaction.